# Unable to install Docker on windows 10

Tags: docker, installation, windows-10, controlled-folder-access

I am trying to install docker on windows machine but it doesn't get install and stop its process in the middle of installation.I have checked for all prerequisite,and my machine fulfills all.
I have NP AV antivirus and it gives me warning like C:\PROGRAM FILES\Docker\RES...\bin\DOCKER_COMPOSE.EXE is a threat after aborting the installation

Comment: What is your windows edition? You need to have Professional or Enterprise since just these versions support hyper-v

Comment: yes it is professional

Comment: @SonalPachpute Does my answer below help?

Comment: Is there anything missing in my answer? (since you just unvoted it)

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on your Windows version (type winver in a CMD)

With 1903, there are reports of freeze or BSOD, with [docker/for-win/issue 3815](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3815).

The main issue regarding the installation is [docker/for-win/issue 1172](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1172),

This assumes that you have Windows Pro at least, with Hyper-V activated (and possibly the antivirus off during installation).

[This thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/installer-for-windows-10-hangs-during-installation/63285/4) includes:

> Adding the downloaded installer `.exe` file to the Controlled Folder Access allowed apps list fixed the problem for me.
>
> `Start | Settings |` and click on `Controlled Folder Access`
>
> T hen click on “`Allow an app through Controlled folder access`”
> Click on the big `+` beside “`Add an allowed app`” and choose `Recently Blocked Apps`.
> Then you can choose the "`Docker for Windows Installer.exe`".
> Re-run the installer as admin and it works.